# How can I find the average of all scores with the same year (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, average

I am using Jupyter Notebook to analyze a .CSV file of movie data. I have created a smaller example to show the problem I have. Below is a sample of years and scores associated to a movie. If a given movie is in the same year I want to find the average of all the movies in that year and display the average in the graph. It is currently only showing the highest score.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = [ 1994, 2008, 2010, 2018, 2018] #year
yy = [ 8.9, 9.0, 8.8, 7.8, 5.2] #scores

plt.bar(xx, yy)
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores over the Years')
plt.show()
```

I have tried a bunch but can't seem to figure it out. If anyone could help I would really apreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib` is a package for visualizing data. For analyzing data (like finding mean years) you can use `pandas` package. I encourage you to read more about it.

For you sample:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Year":[ 1994, 2008, 2010, 2018, 2018], "Score": [ 8.9, 9.0, 8.8, 7.8, 5.2]})
years_list = []
avg_scores = []
for year in np.unique(df["Year"]):
    years_list.append(year)
    avg_scores.append(df.loc[df["Year"]==year, "Score"].mean())

plt.bar(years_list, avg_scores)
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores over the Years')
plt.show()
```

At first I created a dataframe object for storing the data. Then I created a list to hold all years and average score per year. The `for` loop is iterating over all the years, and for each year it averaging the scores over all movies with the same year. The last few lines are just plotting them.

There are more efficient ways to do that with pandas (e.g. `groupby`) but if you are unfamiliar with pandas it may be a little confusion, so I suggest to start from that solution.
The `groupby` solution will work something like that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Year":[ 1994, 2008, 2010, 2018, 2018], "Score": [ 8.9, 9.0, 8.8, 7.8, 5.2]})

plt.bar(df.grouby('Year').mean())
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores over the Years')
plt.show()
```

It's grouping all movies by "Year" column, and takes the average within each group. It map depends a little bit of how your data looks like (if there are any other columns) so don't expect to just copy-paste it.